# Select all path from an Xml that have a content like a graph

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have an XML column with an element like this:

```
<Root>
    <Word Type="pre1" Value="A" />
    <Word Type="pre1" Value="D" />

    <Word Type="base" Value="B" />

    <Word Type="post1" Value="C" />
    <Word Type="post1" Value="E" />
    <Word Type="post1" Value="F" />
</Root>
```

that model something like:

[image]

and want to select all possible path using XQuery in MSSQL to have something like this result:

> ABC 
>   ABE
>   ABF
>   DBC
>   DBE
>   DBF

Or somthing like:

```
<Root>
    <Word Type="pre1" Value="A" />
    <Word Type="pre1" Value="D" />

    <Word Type="pre2" Value="G" />
    <Word Type="pre2" Value="H" />

    <Word Type="base" Value="B" />

    <Word Type="post1" Value="C" />
    <Word Type="post1" Value="E" />
    <Word Type="post1" Value="F" />
</Root>
```

[image]

with this result:

> AHBC 
>   AHBE
>   AHBF
>   DHBC
>   DHBE
>   DHBF
>   AGBC 
>   AGBE
>   AGBF
>   DGBC
>   DGBE
>   DGBF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CTE to build the unique type list and then use that in a recursive CTE to build the strings. Finally you pick out the strings generated in the last iteration.

```sql
with Types as
(
  select row_number() over(order by T.N) as ID,
         T.N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as Type
  from (select @XML.query('for $t in distinct-values(/Root/Word/@Type) 
                           return <T>{$t}</T>')
       ) as X(T)
    cross apply X.T.nodes('/T') as T(N)
),
Recu as
(
  select T.Type,
         T.ID,
         X.N.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)')  as Value
  from Types as T
    cross apply @XML.nodes('/Root/Word[@Type=sql:column("T.Type")]') as X(N)
  where T.ID = 1
  union all
  select T.Type,
         T.ID,
         R.Value+X.N.value('@Value', 'varchar(max)') as Value
  from Types as T
    inner join Recu as R
      on T.ID = R.ID + 1
    cross apply @XML.nodes('/Root/Word[@Type=sql:column("T.Type")]') as X(N)    
)
select R.Value
from Recu as R
where R.ID = (select max(T.ID) from Types as T)
order by R.Value
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3746)

**Update**

Here is a version that have better performance. It shreds the XML to two temp tables. One for each type and one for all words. The recursive CTE is still needed but it uses the tables instead of the XML. There is also one index on each of the temp tables that is used by the joins in the CTE.

```sql
-- Table to hold all values
create table #Values
(
  Type varchar(10),
  Value varchar(10)
);

-- Clustered index on Type is used in the CTE
create clustered index IX_#Values_Type on #Values(Type)

insert into #Values(Type, Value)
select T.N.value('@Type', 'varchar(10)'),
       T.N.value('@Value', 'varchar(10)')
from @XML.nodes('/Root/Word') as T(N);

-- Table that holds one row for each Type
create table #Types
(
  ID int identity,
  Type varchar(10),
  primary key (ID)
);

-- Add types by document order
-- Table-Valued Function Showplan Operator for nodes guarantees document order
insert into #Types(Type)
select T.Type
from (
     select row_number() over(order by T.N) as rn,
            T.N.value('@Type', 'varchar(10)') as Type
     from @XML.nodes('/Root/Word') as T(N)
     ) as T
group by T.Type
order by min(T.rn);

-- Last level of types
declare @MaxID int;
set @MaxID = (select max(ID) from #Types);

-- Recursive CTE that builds the strings
with C as 
(
  select T.ID,
         T.Type,
         cast(V.Value as varchar(max)) as Value
  from #Types as T
    inner join #Values as V
      on T.Type = V.Type
  where T.ID = 1
  union all
  select T.ID,
         T.Type,
         C.Value + V.Value
  from #Types as T
    inner join C
      on T.ID = C.ID + 1
    inner join #Values as V
      on T.Type = V.Type
)
select C.Value
from C
where C.ID = @MaxID
order by C.Value;

-- Cleanup
drop table #Types;
drop table #Values;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12808)

Comment: Thanks @Mikael. Is this solution, guarantee the order of elements base on attribute `Type`?

Comment: @ARZ I thought so but as you can see in the answer from C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, order is not guaranteed when using `distinct-values`. I will post an update with a more "SQL" oriented answer where I don't use `distinct-values` and make use of one (or two) table variables instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need the cross product of these three element sets, so basically write a join without conditions:

```
for $pre  in //Word[@Type="pre1"]
for $base in //Word[@Type="base"]
for $post in //Word[@Type="post1"]
return concat($pre/@Value, $base/@Value, $post/@Value)
```

For the extended version, I used two helper functions which fetch all attributes and then recursively concat the results.

*It seems MSSQL doesn't allow custom XQuery functions. This code is valid for conformant XQuery 1.0 (and newer) processors.*

```
declare function local:call($prefix as xs:string) as xs:string* {
  local:recursion('', 
    for $value in distinct-values(//Word/@Type[starts-with(., $prefix)])
    order by $value
    return $value
  )
};

declare function local:recursion($strings as xs:string*, $attributes as xs:string*) as xs:string* {
  if (empty($attributes))
  then $strings
  else
    for $string in $strings
    for $append in //Word[@Type=$attributes[1]]
    return local:recursion(concat($string, $append/@Value), $attributes[position() != 1])
};

for $pre in local:call('pre')
for $base in local:call('base')
for $post in local:call('post')
return concat($pre, $base, $post)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens, but really the number of loops is not static and depend on XML content! (we may have pre2,pre3,post2,...) so what will be the solution?!

Comment: Post example input, otherwise it's just guessing. How are these connected?

Comment: I updated the answer, too. Only tested in BaseX, but it only uses default XQuery 1.0 and should be running fine in any reasonable implementation.

Comment: I get this error: "**The XQuery syntax 'declare function' is not supported.**"

Comment: If MSSQL doesn't support custom functions, I guess it will get hard to do this in XQuery. I will keep the answer as reference, though.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your XML correctly, all of your graphs are essentially sequences of steps, where no step may be omitted and each step may have several alternatives.  (So the set of paths through the graph is essentially the Cartesian product of the various sets of alternatives.)  If that's not true, what follows won't be what you want.

The easiest way to get the Cartesian product here is to use an XQuery FLWOR expression with one `for` clause for each factor in the Cartesian product, as illustrated in Jens Erat's initial answer.

If you don't know in advance how many factors there will be (because you don't know what sequence of 'Type' values may occur in a graph), and don't want to formulate the query afresh each time, then the simplest thing to do is to write a recursive function which takes a sequence of 'Type' values as one argument and the 'Root' element you're working on as another argument, and handles one factor at a time.

This function does that job, for your sample input:

```
declare function local:cartesian-product(
  $doc as element(),
  $types as xs:string*
) as xs:string* {

  (: If we have no $types left, we are done.
     Return the empty string. :)
  if (empty($types)) then 
     ''

  (: Otherwise, take the first value off the 
     sequence of types and return the Cartesian
     product of all Words with that type and
     the Cartesian product of all the remaining
     types. :)
  else
     let $t := $types[1],
         $rest := $types[position() > 1]
     for $val in $doc/Word[@Type = $t]/@Value
     for $suffix in 
         local:cartesian-product($doc,$rest)
     return concat($val, $suffix)
  };
```

The only remaining problem is the slightly tricky one of getting the sequence of distinct 'Type' values in document order.  We could just call `distinct-values($doc//Word/@Type)` to get the values, but there is no guarantee they will be in document order.

Borrowing from [Dimitre Novatchev's solution to a related problem](https://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2008/11/16/xpath-2-0-gems-find-all-duplicate-values-in-a-sequence-part-2/), we can calculate an appropriate sequence of 'Type' values thus:

```
let $doc := <Root>
    <Word Type="pre1" Value="A" />
    <Word Type="pre1" Value="D" />

    <Word Type="pre2" Value="G" />
    <Word Type="pre2" Value="H" />

    <Word Type="base" Value="B" />

    <Word Type="post1" Value="C" />
    <Word Type="post1" Value="E" />
    <Word Type="post1" Value="F" />
</Root>

let $types0 := ($doc/Word/@Type),
    $types  := $types0[index-of($types0,.)[1]]
```

This returns the distinct values, in document order.

Now we are ready to calculate the result you want:

```
return local:cartesian-product($doc, $types)
```

The results are returned in an order that differs slightly from the order you give; I assume you do not care about the sequence of results:

AGBC AGBE AGBF AHBC AHBE AHBF DGBC DGBE DGBF DHBC DHBE DHBF

Comment: This is probably more general, but I wasn't sure if the attributes always occur in document order, so I traded being more general for a solution in which you can define the order. I guess he'll have the same problem with your solution like with mine: MSSQL not supporting custom functions...